# Rendering partials from a helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is it possible to render a partial using a helper method where you can also pass local variables from the view in which the helper method is called?  For example, when I include this code directly in the view, it renders the partial properly:

```
 <%= render :partial => "add_round", :locals => { :f => f } %>
```

Then I moved it to a helper method:

```
def addRound
  render :partial => "add_round", :locals => { :f => f }
end
```

Then I called it from the view again with:

```
 <%= addRound %>
```

This did not work with the :locals => { :f => f } included in the code.  It returned this error: undefined local variable or method `f'.  However, the addRound method did render something with the following:

```
def addRound
  render :partial => "add_round"
end
```

Writing it this way allowed me to render partials that didn't require the local variables to be passed through (such as plain text strings).  But how can I get it to work with the :locals => { :f => f } included?  Is there another way to write that?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Pass `f` as a parameter in helper's method

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to pass `f` to `addRound`

```
def addRound(f)
  render partial: "add_round", locals: { f: f }
end
```

and in the view

```
<%= addRound(f) %>
```

Comment: Thanks Deefour.  That worked perfectly (hopefully was just a rookie mistake on my part).  I have a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358993/add-section-to-form-by-rendering-a-partial-when-link-is-clicked.  Specifically, I can't get the javascript call on the link_to to do what it is supposed to do (to call the addRound method when clicked).  Any ideas on that?  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help; looks like you got someone else helping with the other question. Good luck.